# React native facebook ad deeplink issue

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-fbsdk

My deeplink is not working.  I have integrated fbsdk and when I click on an ad on fb then it will take me to playstore/appstore for app install (which is normal behaviour). But after the installation of app I received null in deeplink url in my app.js .

```
Url scheme I am using is: myapp://test
react-naative-fbsdk version : "^1.1.1"
react-native version : "0.61.5"
```

I have added

```
<data
     android:host="test"
     android:scheme="myapp" />
```

in my app's manifest file.
but still no luck.

I have followed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking for this purpose.

Any can help.